# How I can deserialize in borsh UnorderedMap? Near

Tags: rust, near

How I can deserialize in borsh UnorderedMap?

Now my schema is

```
const schema = new Map([
  [
    Record,
    {
      kind: "struct",
      fields: [
        ["x2", { kind: 'map', key: 'string', value: 'u128'}],
      ],
    },
  ],
]);
```

Rust struct:

```
pub struct Counter {
    x2: UnorderedMap<AccountId, Balance>,
}
```

But I have error: `"Expected buffer length 2036811841 isn't within bounds"`

Comment: not saying your schema is wrong, but it looks pretty weird.